# I want different keyboard for different textField for sign up form

Tags: xcode

I want to show the user number-pad keyboard with done button when they click on tfZip textField and otherwise simple.But my problem is the done button is shown on every keyboard.Please help, I search 3-4 hours but not get proper answer.

Clearly, I have textField and one of those is Zip.Now I set different Keyboard for different textField."**When I first click textField accept Zip textField its ok(keyboard) and then click on Zip textField I get no Done button on the keyboard."**

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    if(!(textField == tfZip))
    {
        doneButton.hidden=YES;
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // create custom button

    doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Done.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Done_select.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [doneButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(doneButton:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIView *keyboardView = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] subviews] firstObject];
            [doneButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardView.frame.size.height - 53, 106, 53)];
            [keyboardView addSubview:doneButton];
            [keyboardView bringSubviewToFront:doneButton];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]-.02
                                  delay:.0
                                options:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]
                             animations:^{
                                 self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, 0);
                             } completion:nil];
        });
    } else {
        // locate keyboard view
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
            UIView* keyboard;
            for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
                keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
                if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                    [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
            }
        });
    }
}

- (void)doneButton:(id)sender
{
    [tfZip resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(!(textField==tfZip))
    {
        doneButton.hidden=NO;
    }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you can set keyboard type from nib or storyboard directly and also set return key type.. or by code like [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

Comment: I do that programmically.

Comment: I change the code litle. Now when I click on any text field keyboard show done button,then 2nd time click on other text field it's show right keyboard

Comment: do your code in textFieldShouldBeginEditing to hide and unhide or other actions.

Comment: Sir, what you edited? I face same problem till.@mohacs

Answer (score 0):

use textfield delegate method for done button showing only for your tfZip

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

     if(textField==tfZip)
     {
          doneButton.hidden=NO;
     }
     else
    {
          doneButton.hidden=YES;
     }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: It's not working, same problem button doesn't hide for first click

Comment: then make use of toolbar and add done button in it. then set [tfZip setInputAccessoryView:toolbar]; then forget about other textfield. it shows only for textfield to which it set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Now done button is appeared top of the keyboard and it is working perfectly. Can I fix it at bottom where the empty place of numberpad keyboard occure

Comment: if there are empty space.. then don't set it as input accessory, but do set frame of toolbar when you need to place and show.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You need to have check inside - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note; before adding done button as subview.